# How can I ensure that async initialization in the Angular service constructor is completed?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs5

Experts, please tell me how to make sure that asynchronous initialization in the service constructor is complete when calling other functions in the class?

```
  constructor() {
    var sock = new SockJS(this._chatUrl);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(sock);
    this.stompClient.connect({}, function () {
    });
  }

  public subscribe(topicName: string, messageReceived) {
    this.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/' + topicName, function (message) {
      messageReceived(message);
    })
  }

  public sendMessage(msgDestId: string, message) {
    this.stompClient.send("/app/" + msgDestId, {}, JSON.stringify(message));
  }
```

As you can see, the connection to the stomp-server is established in the constructor. After that, customers (components) of this service are invited to subscribe to topics of interest. Naturally, the call to the subscribe function does not make sense until the connection is fully established.

**Update:**
It is also important to keep .connect method called only once. Otherwise it creates two connections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make every interaction with the stomp client through a promise, e.g.:

```
constructor() {
    ...
    this.stomp = new Promise(resolve => {
        stompClient.connect({}, () => resolve(stompClient));
    });
}

subscribe(...) {
    this.stomp.then(stompClient => stompClient.subscribe(...));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Will it also work even after multiple subscriptions when connection is established looong time ago?

Comment: Sure, you can use the promise's `then` method over and over and will get the resolved value from it every time.

Comment: This almost works. Unfortunately, it connects twice with this code. Is there a way to ensure that code in the Promise is executed only once?

Comment: This code does not connect twice, no. It's something in your code.

Comment: It turned out that the problem was because angular creates instance for each 'providers' defined in each component. To avoid this issue I had to define service in 'providers' section of parent module. Thanks!