# How to solve time raise problems in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I am writing an Angular Service to prove a Users permissions. In the constructor I want to get the current logged in user from an API. The current User which is created is used in other methods of this Service. This Methods are called from components to check which things can be shown and so on. 
The problem is that the methods in the service are called faster than the current user is available.
Are there any possibilities solving this issue?

**permission.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class PermissionService {
  currUser = {
    'id': "",
    'permission': ""
  };
  apiService: AlfrescoApiService;
  authService: AuthenticationService;

  constructor(apiService: AlfrescoApiService, authService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.apiService = apiService;
    this.authService = authService;

    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    let userId: string = this.authService.getEcmUsername();    
    this.currUser.id = userId;

//API call
    this.apiService.sitesApi.getSiteMember(SITENAME, userId).then(resp => {
      this.currUser.permission = resp.entry.role;
    })
  }

  isSiteManager(): boolean {
    console.log(this.currUser.permission, this.currUser);
    if(this.currUser.permission === "SiteManager"){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**method call**

```
export class AppLayoutComponent {

  constructor(permissionService:PermissionService) {
    permissionService.isSiteManager();
  }

}
```

**output in Google Chrome**

> {id: "admin", permission: ""}
>   id: "admin"permission: "SiteManager"

Comment: `the methods in the service are called faster than the current user is available` - the word you're looking for is *asynchrony* ... i.e. `this.currUser.permission = resp.entry.role;` is executed asynchronously, but your code suggests you don't know this

Comment: Yes I know that it is asyc. However I have no idea to solve this.

Comment: It depends on how you use the result of `isSiteManager()` and whether or not the application uses the Angular Router.

Answer (score 1):

You should use promise in your getEcmUsername() handle this; after that you can code like this
`

```
this.authService.getEcmUsername().then((userID) => {
    this.apiService.sitesApi.getSiteMember(SITENAME, userId).then(resp => {
      this.currUser.permission = resp.entry.role;
    })
});
```

`

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. "getEcmUsername()" gives back a string.

Comment: You can use `return Promise.resolve(string)`  in your getEcmUsername method

Comment: this may help you [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45090069/7235892] just need to wrap your init function in promise or use async/await

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion better solution is to use Observable here and rxjs. In service you can create Subject and subscribe it inside your compnent, to be sure data is already there. E.g.:

```
@Injectable()
export class PermissionService {
 public Subject<bool> userFetched= new Subject<bool>();
  currUser: IUser = {
    'id': "",
    'permission': ""
  };
  apiService: AlfrescoApiService;
  authService: AuthenticationService;

  constructor(apiService: AlfrescoApiService, authService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.apiService = apiService;
    this.authService = authService;

    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    let userId: string = this.authService.getEcmUsername();    
    this.currUser.id = userId;

//API call
    this.apiService.sitesApi.getSiteMember(SITENAME, userId).subscribe((data:IUser)=> 
  {
    this.user=data;
   this.userFetched.next(true);
  })
 }

  isSiteManager(): boolean {
    console.log(this.currUser.permission, this.currUser);
    if(this.currUser.permission === "SiteManager"){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

After that in your component:

```
export class AppLayoutComponent {

  constructor(permissionService:PermissionService) {
    permissionService.userFetched.subscribe((data)=>{
     permissionService.isSiteManager();
  });
  }
}
```

It's better approach. You need to consider if better is Subject or BehaviourSubject.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody who answered. I have found a solution. I have changed the `isSiteManager()` method to a method which checks all four permissiontypes. This method is executed in the `then()` block and affects four variables for each permissiontype. These variables i can reach from other components.
**Looks like this:**

```
 @Injectable()
export class PermissionService {
  isSiteManager: boolean;
  isSiteConsumer: boolean;
  isSiteContributor: boolean;
  isSiteCollaborator: boolean;
  userId : string;

  constructor(private apiService: AlfrescoApiService, private authService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.isSiteCollaborator = false;
    this.isSiteConsumer = false;
    this.isSiteContributor = false;
    this.isSiteManager = false;
    this.userId = localStorage.USER_PROFILE;

    //proof permission of user
    this.apiService.sitesApi.getSiteMember(SITENAME, this.userId).then(resp=>{
      if(resp.entry.role === "SiteManager"){
        this.isSiteManager = true;
      }else if(resp.entry.role === "SiteConsumer"){
        this.isSiteConsumer = true;
      }else if(resp.entry.role === "SiteContributor"){
        this.isSiteContributor = true;
      }else{
        this.isSiteCollaborator = true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Now i can ask for the variables in other components like this:**

```
export class AppLayoutComponent {

  constructor(private permissionService : PermissionService) {
    if(permissionService.isSiteManager){
      console.log("You are Boss!");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should call your service method synchrony. To do so, you have to map your response from the service:

your component code:

```
constructor() {
...
permissionService.isSiteManager().map(
response => {
    isManager = response;
}
);
}
```

Something like this.

To call map operator import it before:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Comment: Use `.subscribe()`

Comment: @kvetis you are wrong, subscribe is async. Author need sync call

Comment: `isSiteManager` doesn't return an observable. If it would: how does your answer solve the problem?

Comment: I think you need to brush up Observables. Both `.map` and `.subscribe` are async. I also agree with @abetteroliver , even if you used `.subscribe` OP would need to rewrite the `isSiteManager`